# Duplicates 101 from basic search to delete?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates, delete-row

Goal is to find duplicates.

```
Select Column1, Column2, Column3 
from Tablename
where Column1 = 1111 and Column2 = 2222
group by Column1, Column2, Column3 
having count(*) > 1
```

This `select` query finds all the rows that are duplicates. I want to delete them all so I changed `select` to `delete`:

```
Delete from Tablename
where Column1 = 1111 and Column2 = 2222
group by Column1, Column2, Column3 
having count(*) > 1
```

I get an error that says I can't use "group by".

What is another option to delete them all?

Comment: Are you sure you want to delete them all? Or do you want to leave one row for the ones that were duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
with v1 as
(select 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column1) AS ID,t1.*
FROM Tablename t1)
DELETE FROM v1 where Column1=1111 and Column2=2222
and id not in (select min(id) from v1 group by
              Column1, Column2, Column3);
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c55e/2)